# Java - for loop: distribution

Tags: java, for-loop

How can I distribute 510 children over 8 parents so that I have 64 of them on each of the first 7, and the rest 62 on the 8th, with their IDs ranging from 9 to 72 for each parent.

So far I have this:

```
// first 7 parents will have 64 children each, 8th parent will have 62 children
for(int child = 1; child <= maxNumChildren; child++) {
    setTestStep("Create Child = " + child + " on Parent = " + ((child/65) + 1)  + " with childId = " + ( 9 + ((child- 1) % 64)));
    childList[child - 1] = createChild(parentList[child/65], child, "" + ( 9 + ((child- 1) % 64)));
}
```

It's wrong because the 129th child is created on the 2nd insted of the 3rd parent and so on.

Can you please help me with this?

P.S. Sorry if I'm using some wrong terminology, I'm a beginner.

Comment: 2 loops would make things more clear IMHO

Comment: Instead of using `child - 1` start at `child = 0` and use `/64` instead of `/65`

Comment: Is `clildList` secretly `childList`?

Comment: Edited: clildList is childList. Thank you:)

Comment: I actually did it with 2 loops at the beginning and it worked, but a senior programmer said it's too long and said to do it this way..

Comment: @user2576486 - Not sure I understand your senior programmers objection. Unless this is going to cause massive overheads your better off going with readability over some tiny performance improvements.

Comment: @Rudi, I completely agree, however, It was not my call unfortunately:/

Answer (score 0):

This should produce the correct result.

```
final int step = 64;
for (int i = 0; i < maxNumChildren; i += step) {
    for (int j = i; j < Math.min(maxNumChildren, i+step); j++) {
        childList[j] = createChild(parentList[i/step], j+1, "" + (9+j-i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the index arithmetic isses you are having by using zero-based indexing.

```
// first 7 parents will have 64 children each,
// 8th parent will have 62 children
for(int childIndex = 0; childIndex < maxNumChildren; childIndex++) {
    setTestStep("Create Child = " + (childIndex + 1) +
                " on Parent = " + ((childIndex / 64) + 1)  +
                " with childId = " + ( 9 + childIndex % 64));
    childList[childIndex] = createChild(parentList[childIndex / 64],
                                        child, "" + ( 9 + (childIndex % 64));
}
```